# ¿Es posible correr un fichero JavaScript en modo sandbox?

Tags: javascript, html5, sandbox

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en el que otros programadores pueden colaborar con su propio código HTML + JavaScript. Por motivos de seguridad no quiero que su código JavaScript tenga acceso total al sistema, aunque sí me interesa que tenga algo de acceso (p.e. su código podría llamar a algunas funciones propias del sitio, pero no quiero que pueda usar AJAX o similares):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy mirando la posibilidad de crear un `iframe` en el que se ejecutaría el HTML + JS del programador en modo [`sandbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/iframe#attr-sandbox)  (para que no pueda afectar a la página superior) y combinarlo con [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) y una API interna para permitir cierta comunicación bidireccional.

...eso me funciona, pero me genera problemas de visualización: en el `iframe` puede haber elementos que se arrastran y que se verían cortados si el usuario los mueve hacia los límites del `iframe` (y me interesa que para el usuario no haya diferencia entre sitio e `iframe`).

¿Es posible descartar el `iframe` y poner el código del programador directamente en la página a ser posible de manera segura? Es decir, ¿sería posible correr su fichero JS en modo sandbox o limitar las funciones que ejecuta? (de manera similar a como lo haría un  `iframe` en `sandbox`):

```
<script src="/ruta/a/js/del/usuario.js" sandbox></script>
```

Sé que eso no funciona porque la etiqueta `script` no tiene atributo `sandbox`, pero ¿existe algo similar? Y si no, ¿cómo se podría simular?

Comment: Dentro del explorador podrías asolarlo usando Webworkers, pero van a tener acceso al DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta con modificar el contexto *Window* antes de ejecutar el script.

```js
var cache = {
  XMLHttpRequest : Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'XMLHttpRequest')  
}

delete window.XMLHttpRequest // elimina XMLHttpRequest

//========= SANDBOX ==================================
try 
  {
    var fallo = new XMLHttpRequest(); // lanza Error
  } 
catch(e)
  { 
    console.log('Error al usar AJAX')
  }
//====================================================

Object.defineProperty(window, 'XMLHttpRequest', cache.XMLHttpRequest) // restaura XMLHttpRequest
```

Como puedes ver, sólo se trata de eliminar dichas funcionalidades.

Comment: Solo faltaria ofuscar el código

Comment: Preguntas: ¿podría el usuario redefinir esas funciones o crear una nueva ventana que si las tuviera? ¿Y podría el código de la página seguir utilizándolas de alguna manera? (no quiero que el código del otro programador haga llamadas AJAX, pero yo debería seguir teniendo esa funcionalidad de algún modo)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Respondo 
1. Sí podrá redefinirlas pero sin éxito alguno
2. Sí puede crear ventanas con `window.open()` que efectivamente podrán usar para acceder a AJAX, no obstante, basta bloquear `window.open()` y similares desde el principio, siguiendo la misma técnica expuesta para XMLHttpRequest
3. Tú si puedes utilizar AJAX, la última línea restaura XMLHttpRequest, es decir que todo lo colocado después de esa línea puede ejecutar AJAX.

Comment: Ok. Deja que haga algunas pruebas. Me da que voy a tener que redefinir bastantes cosas.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ¿puedes escribir exactamente qué buscas?,mi respuesta sólo da una general detrás del "sandbox" puedes crear toda una API partiendo de ella. No obstante, no puedo darte una implementación especifica a tu necesidad sin conocer el escenario completo, valores de entrada, y valores de salida correspondientes.

Comment: He editado la pregunta. Esta respuesta funciona, pero me encuentro con que como es en JS, incluso si se ofuscara el código, en algún momento alguien podría encontrar qué es lo que estoy haciendo y saltarse mis restricciones.